# How can I split a string given a specific format?

Tags: javascript, string-formatting, date-formatting

I have dates in  string format that sometimes are like this: `05-11-2009 16:59:20` and sometime are like this: `2013-12-05T22:00:00:00Z` and some other time are like this: `2013-12-05T22:00:00:00.000Z`.

I wrote a function that extract the month day and year from those dates, but I would like a function that can work for all of them passing in input the format.
something like:

```
function DateParts(datetime, format) {
    var matches = datetime.splitByFormat(format);

    this.getYear = function () {
       return matches[3];
    };
    this.getMonth = function () {
        return (matches[2] - 1) +"" ;
    };
    this.getDay = function () {
        return matches[1];
    };
    this.getHours = function () {
        return matches[4];
    };
    this.getMinutes = function () {
    return matches[5];
    };
    this.getSeconds = function () {
        return matches[6];
    };
};
```

Where format will be soething like `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss"` or `"dd-mm-yyyyThh:MM:ss.dddZ"` or whatever.

Is there a nice way of creating the splitByFormat function without having to substring my head off?

Comment: Someones got to have a lovely regex for this :)

Comment: `"or whatever"` is probably a bit vague to write code for. Is this JavaScript?

Comment: sorry added the javascript tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple class `FormatAnalyzer` could be a beginning. It works.

```
FormatAnalyzer f = new FormatAnalyzer("yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss");
f.getYear("2013-07-11 15:39:00");
f.getMonth("2013-07-11 15:39:00");
```

where

```
public class FormatAnalyzer {

    private String format;
    private int yearBegin;
    private int yearEnd;
    private int monthBegin;
    private int monthEnd;
    // ...

    public FormatAnalyzer(String format) {
        this.format = format;
        analyzeFormat();
    }

    public String getYear(String date) {
        return date.substring(yearBegin, yearEnd);
    }

    public String getMonth(String date) {
        return date.substring(monthBegin, monthEnd);
    }

    private void analyzeFormat() {
        yearBegin = yearEnd = format.indexOf("y");
        while (format.indexOf("y", ++yearEnd) != -1) {
        }
        monthBegin = monthEnd = format.indexOf("m");
        while (format.indexOf("m", ++monthEnd) != -1) {
        }
        // and so on for year, day, ...
    }
}
```

Comment: With this class, you have to analyze the format just once, and then every date analysis reduces to substring extractions, for the given format. It could be computationally fast.

Comment: Best solution so far. but maybe you could pass the date in the constructor at the beginning together with the format...

Comment: First of all: sorry because I've written Java code, cause had not figured out you needed JS. In my intention, you make an instance of FormatAnalyzer for every kind of format, and once instantiated you can use that instance with all dates you need.

Answer (score 2):

One regex to find them all:

```
(((?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})-(?<year>\d{4})\s(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minute>\d{2}):(?<second>\d{2}))|((?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})T(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minute>\d{2}):(?<second>\d{2}):(?<millisecond>\d{2})Z)|(?<year>(\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})T(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minute>\d{2}):(?<second>\d{2}):(?<millisecond>\d{2})\.(?<centisecond>\d{3})Z))
```

If you use this regex string, you are able to just capture the different groupings:

- year
- month
- day
- hour
- minute
- second
- millisecond
- centisecond

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd variations seems identical except for the last part, couldn't you just have made `\.(?<centisecond>\d{3})` optional?

Comment: Yeah, would be simpler. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

What about this? anything better anyone?

```
function DateParts(datetime, format) {

    this.getYear = function () {
        if (format) {
            ind = format.indexOf("yyyy");
            return datetime.substring(ind, ind + 4);
        }
         return "";

    };
    this.getMonth = function () {
        if (format) {
            ind = format.indexOf("mm");
            return datetime.substring(ind, ind + 2);
        }
        return "";            
    };
    this.getDay = function () {
        if (format) {
            ind = format.indexOf("gg");
            return datetime.substring(ind, ind + 2);
       }
       return "";
    };
};
```